# Type I Vacuum fluctuations

Tags: particle-physics, vacuum

Type one Parapositronium borrow energy from the vacuum to pop into existence, returning it after annihilation. Halfway through reading [this eye opening paper about Vacuum fluctuations](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10701-020-00339-3) this one (probably silly) question arrised: Does Parapositronium only exist under complete vacuum circumstances or does it, for example, also form in the atmosphere?[answered] And if so: Does all space possess a *ground state* energy such as the one observed in complete Vacuum?

EDIT: After finding papers ([1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0301010415002219), [2](http://przyrbwn.icm.edu.pl/APP/PDF/132/app132z5p05.pdf)) answering my first question, I have a followup: Where from do the Positronium borrow their energy while on a medium?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium#Natural_occurrence might be helpful.

Comment: This lead me to find some articles in which they talk about Positronium in different mediums like [this one](http://przyrbwn.icm.edu.pl/APP/PDF/132/app132z5p05.pdf) and [this one](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0301010415002219). But they only talk about ortho-Positronium and there is no mention of para-Positronium.

Comment: Correction: The latter paper does talk about para-Positronium.  Where from do the Positronium borrow their energy while on a medium?

Comment: "the positron source 22Na with activity10μCi was tightly sealed in7μmthick envelope made of Kapton foil. "  from  your link 2; the positrons do not come from vacuum fluxuations but from a nuclear decay.

Comment: In general for vacuum fluctuations to become on shell, energy must be supplied. Otherwise they are just virtual particles useful for mathematical solutions.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but do not Type I Positronium pairs that come from vacuum fluctuations interact with photons, becoming on shell without any external energy (to afterwards anihilate and return the photon without any alterations)? And thanks for clarying that about the paper. @annav

Comment: @Wilhelmroentgen in this case the photon provides the energy for the interaction so that real four vectors (on shell)  can appear. If they do not appear (i.e. become onshell) they are just a useful mathematical model for whatever is calculated.